# Select values by type with maximum value

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table

| Type | Subtype | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | PT1 | 3 |
| T1 | PT2 | 2 |
| T2 | PT11 | 3 |
| T2 | PT12 | 5 |

It is necessary to select from it the names of subtypes for each type with the largest number
that is, it should turn out

| Subtype |
| --- |
| PT1 |
| PT12 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is using `WITH TIES` in concert with the window function `row_number() over ()`

```
Select top 1 with ties
       Subtype
 From  YourTable
 Order By row_number() over (partition by [type] order by quantity desc)
```

or you can use a subquery (a nudge more performant)

```
Select Subtype
 From  (
        Select *
              ,RN = By row_number() over (partition by [type] order by quantity desc)
         From YourTable 
       ) A
Where RN=1
```